# Multiple Cell Types in Android ListView

Tags: android, listview

What I'm trying to do is to show some data for a book like Title, Author, and a Cover, and beneath these data, to have a ListView containing a list of clickable chapters.

One way I've thought would be to have a ListView with different type of cells, where the first would contain the data, and the rest of them would be simple cells containing the chapters. The ListView binds to a custom CursorAdapter that implements the newView(...) and bindView(...) methods, which I don't know how to customise in order to return different types of cells based on the cell's position.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TITLE)));
    ..
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookcell, parent, false);
    bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;
}
```

How should I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by:

1. Overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and returning the number of distinct row layouts
2. Overriding `getItemViewType()` and returning a 0-based index of the row layout to be used for a given `position`
3. Adjusting `newView()` and `bindView()` to use the right row type based on the position (e.g., `newView()` inflates different row layouts based on `position`)

Or, you can try assembling your adapter from pieces, using something like my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge).

Comment: How should I adjust the newView and bindView? They don't get a position argument... Could you provide a code sample? Thanks!

Comment: @georgeb89: Your position can be found by calling `getPosition()` on your `Cursor`.

Comment: Hmm.. I tried to do that, but now I realize that the data come from two different datasets (one for the Chapters and one for the rest of the book details), so I would need 2 different Cursors... :S

Comment: @georgeb89: A join might work, if you are querying SQLite. Otherwise, yes, you will need your own rather sophisticated adapter to blend the two cursors into the header-and-detail model you're seeking.

Comment: Could I use your own MergeAdapter to solve the issue? I'm querying SQLite but I wouldn't like to use a join...

Comment: @georgeb89: `MergeAdapter` isn't quite set up for your scenario. In your case, you have a single `CursorAdapter` (all chapters) which you want split up into segments with interspersed headers. `MergeAdapter` is designed for a bunch of smaller `CursorAdapters` (one per book) and interspersed headers.